# WSO2 SingleSign ON

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2

I am new to WSO2 and I follow [this post](http://sureshatt.blogspot.pt/2012/11/how-to-enable-sso-for-wso2-server.html?showComment=1368530322906#c761185918564837408) to enable Single Sign On (SSO) for the following scenario:

- Virtual machine running centos (IP: 192.168.0.18)
- WSO2 IdentityServer 4.1.0 installed with https port: 9443
- WSO2 ApplicationServer 5.1.0 installed with https port: 9443

Here is the problem:

- when I access the application server console management, I am
  redirected to the identity provider login page as expected and I can
  login.
- I am then redirected to the initial request (Application Server MGT
  Console) but a message appears telling me that the
  Authentication/Authorization fails.

**In log files I can see following error:**

> TID: [0] [AS] [2013-05-14 16:13:32,128]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common.builders.AuthenticationRequestBuilder}
>   -  Building Authentication Request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common.builders.AuthenticationRequestBuilder}
>   TID: [0] [AS] [2013-05-14 16:13:32,388] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.util.Util} - 
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.util.Util} TID: [0]
>   [AS] [2013-05-14 16:13:32,389] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator}
>   -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error occured while processing saml2 response
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator}
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticatorException:
>   Error occured while processing saml2 response
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.util.Util.unmarshall(Util.java:87)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator.login(SAML2SSOAuthenticator.java:64)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

I search the net for this error but I was not able to find something that could help me to solve this problem.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to a version difference between the SAML components being used in the two servers. We will make a public patch available.

Comment: I, thanks for your answer. Where can I check for the patch to be avalaible? Is there another way for me to test SSO throught multiple WSO2 products, How can I verify the saml components versions?

Comment: Hi, I manage to make Single Sign On works between diferents WSO2 Products. As you said the problem was due to a version difference between the SAML components being used on those servers.
So I had to install WSO2 Products based on carbon 4.0.3 to make it work. I thought that installing WSO2 Products as separate servers will allow me to use the latest versions of each product. In that case, is there anyway to make an update of the WSO2 Products to recent versions when this problem will be solved?

Thanks you!

Comment: Hi guys, this will be fixed very soon as there is already a task for this [1], patches will be publicly available in the jira ticket itself[1].  

[1]-https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1043

Comment: Hi, I unzipped the patch into the Identity Server patches folder (repository/components/patches) and run this server with the -DapplyPatches option, I checked that the patched jars are now in the plugins folder but I'm still getting the error that follows when trying to authenticate AS Server through IdentityServer:

[2013-07-03 11:03:06,564]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common.builders.AuthenticationRequestBuilder} -  Building Authentication Request
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Am I missing any step?